# Deploying Frontend and Backend separately for Rails on same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, apache2, rails-api

We have made a rails app with foundation framework for frontend and using rails api for backend. In development environment, I was using apache2 for frontend and webrick for backend. So, I was sending all json requests to localhost:3000.

On production environment, I have already deployed the frontend using apache2 and was trying to deploy backend with nginx and passenger but they both use the same port. Can anyone suggest a solution to this. Ideally, I want a URL similar to my localhost (like 104.xx.xx.xx:3031) on production.

Answer (score 0):

You can run nginix on diff port 
Try this

```
#server config
server {
    listen       8083;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/project_path/;
         passenger_enabled on;
    }


error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Put this in nginx config file